# R: Replacing values of one list element with values of a second list element

Tags: r, list, replace, row

I want to replace the values of one element of a list with the values of a second element of a list. Specifically,

I have a list containing multiple data sets.

Each data set has 2 variables

The variables are factors

The n'th element of the second variable of each data set needs to be replaced with the n'th element of the first variable in each data set

Also, the replaced value should be called "replaced"

```
dat1 <- data.frame(names1 =c("a", "b", "c", "f", "x"),values= c("val1_1", "val2_1", "val3_1", "val4_1", "val5_1"))
   dat1$values <- as.factor(dat1$values)
dat2 <- data.frame(names1 =c("a", "b", "f2", "s5", "h"),values= c("val1_2", "val2_2", "val3_2", "val4_2", "val5_2"))
   dat2$values <- as.factor(dat2$values)
list1 <- list(dat1, dat2)
```

The result should be the same list, but just with the 5th value replaced.

```
[[1]]
     names1  values
1         a  val1_1
2         b  val2_1
3         c  val3_1
4         f  val4_1
5  replaced       x
[[2]]
     names1  values
1         a  val1_2
2         b  val2_2
3        f2  val3_2
4        s5  val4_2
5  replaced       h
```

Comment: This is a simplified example. I have more than 4500 data sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R approach using `lapply`, since both the columns are factors we need to add new `levels` first before replacing them with new values otherwise those value would turn as `NA`s.

```
n <- 5

lapply(list1, function(x) {
   levels(x$values) <- c(levels(x$values), as.character(x$names1[n]))
   x$values[n] <- x$names1[n]
   levels(x$names1) <- c(levels(x$names1), "replaced")
   x$names1[n] <- "replaced"
   x
})

#[[1]]
#    names1 values
#1        a val1_1
#2        b val2_1
#3        c val3_1
#4        f val4_1
#5 replaced      x

#[[2]]
#    names1 values
#1        a val1_2
#2        b val2_2
#3       f2 val3_2
#4       s5 val4_2
#5 replaced      h
```

There is also another approach where we can convert both the columns to characters, then replace the values at required position and again convert them back to factors but since every dataframe in the list can be huge we do not want to convert all the values to characters and then back to factor just to change one value which could be computationally very expensive.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `tidyverse`.  Loop through the `list` with `map`, `slice` the row of interest (in this case, it is the last row, so `n()` can be used), `mutate` the column value and bind with the original data without the last row

```
library(tidyverse)
map(list1, ~ .x %>% 
               slice(n()) %>%
               mutate(values = names1, names1 = 'replaced') %>% 
               bind_rows(.x %>% slice(-n()), .))
#[[1]]
#    names1 values
#1        a val1_1
#2        b val2_1
#3        c val3_1
#4        f val4_1
#5 replaced      x

#[[2]]
#    names1 values
#1        a val1_2
#2        b val2_2
#3       f2 val3_2
#4       s5 val4_2
#5 replaced      h
```

---

Or it can be made more compact with `fct_c` from `forcats`.  Different `factor` levels can be combined together with `fct_c` for the 'values' and 'names1' column

```
library(forcats)
map(list1, ~ .x %>% 
        mutate(values = fct_c(values[-n()], names1[n()]), 
               names1 = fct_c(names1[-n()], factor('replaced'))))
```

---

Or using similar approach with `base R` where we loop through the `list` with `lapply`, then convert the `data.frame` to `matrix`, `rbind` the subset of matrix i.e. the last row removed with the values of interest, and convert to `data.frame` (by default, `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` - so it gets converted to `factor`)

```
lapply(list1,  function(x)  as.data.frame(rbind(as.matrix(x)[-5, ], 
              c('replaced',  as.character(x$names1[5])))))
```

Comment: How do you get to the row number, Akrun? is n <- 5 used from the above answer?

Comment: @tobiassch  No, Here, you have only 5 rows, and `n()` is the last row.  If you have a custom `n`, then use that in `slice(n)`

Comment: Yes! I see, will try!